webflux eventSource.onmessage not work but returned correctly
Frontend code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>EventSource Stream Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Real-time Updates</h1>
    <div id="messages"></div>

    <script>
        const eventSource = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:8083/api/webflux?msg=hello');

        eventSource.onmessage = (event) =>  {
            const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
            messageElement.textContent = event.data;
            document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(messageElement);
        };

        eventSource.onerror = (event) => {
            console.error("EventSource failed: ", event);
            const errorElement = document.createElement('div');
            errorElement.style.color = 'red';
            errorElement.textContent = 'An error occurred, check the console for details.';
            document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(errorElement);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Backend Code
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Slf4j
@CrossOrigin
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/webflux", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> testFlux(String msg) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(strings).interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map(e -> e + " " + msg);
    }
}

enter image description here
The program returned correctly.，Why can't the onmessage method trigger?
eventSource.onmessage not work eventSource.onerror can work
